# How to stop stray dogs & puppies from following me

Tags: dogs, behavior

Most of the stray puppies/dogs I feed keep following me. When its time for me to go home, I cannot since they are always following me. Some puppies stop at the end of their territory, but others just keep following.

I searched the net, which said training is the solution, but I cannot train them.

How do I stop them from following me? Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let them follow you, but ignore them on the way home!
They don't get attention, treats, love, anything when following. They DO get all of that in the spots where you decide to feed them. Hopefully, most of them will be smart enough to realize "This guy is part of our group when he is here. When he leaves, he leaves. Then he comes back to be with us again. That is great!" :)

Answer (score 2):

You have made yourself a save and stable source of food for those dogs. And so you have started the process of taming those dogs into pets.

Options:

**1 -** Adopt one, stop feeding the rest. Now you have just 1 dog following you.

**2 -** Stop feeding the dogs.

**3 -** Feed them in a way that does not make a connection between you and food. Not sure how to go about this, for animals are very good at this.

---

Unless you plan on adopting a stray, may I suggest you stop feeding them? With more food there will be more puppies and more dogs to feed. You will run out of dog food before they will run out of space to breed...

Comment: only 5% of puppies survive in India. I will try to open an animal shelter this summer vacation. They feed on garbage, and I feed them treats. I am building friendship with each one of them that will help me in neutering programs ahead. I am giving them the love they deserve. Telling them that there is some good in this world. I am giving them love after the horrifying stones they are hit with, the huge cars they are ran over with. In return I am getting more love. I cannot stop feeding them just to make them stop following me. Thank you.

Comment: Puppies don't understand the big picture. They don't know, hey I am a stray dog and this is a human which will return to his home after having some fun with us. All they know is that you are giving them food and that you are "building friendship". They want to include you into their pack and a pack always stays together. So there is simply no way to stop them following, if you are so nice to them (which is wonderful! Especially if you try to get them neutered.).

Comment: @HarasBrummi thank you. I will try to open an animal shelter through crowdfunding and then a sterilisation program as well. thank you.